# Is there a way to add a custom action to Azure DevOps Pull Requests?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to solve this flow:

1. Developer opens a PR.
2. Build validation finds some static code rules are being broken.
3. Developer has the option to ask for a manual review, this is some kind of action that can be performed from the PR (a button click, link, etc.) that will automatically open a DevOps work item.

I can solve the opening of an automatic WI, but is there any way to add a custom button on PRs? Maybe using extensions?

I saw the service hooks, but these are triggered automatically, I need something that will be triggered manually directly from the PR.

Thanks!